# Facebook api picture size for group members using nested query?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I really like the nested query but I am not sure if there is a way to return the `picture` with some `width` and/or `height` parameters?

Docs on nested query https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion I cannot find anything.

```
FB.api('/554870764588961?fields=members{id,name,picture}', function (response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.members.data.length; i++) { 
        facebookPlayers.push({
            player_name:response.members.data[i].name ,
            player_picture:response.members.data[i].picture.data.url
        });
    }
    callback(facebookPlayers);
});
```

Basically I want to do what I am doing above but in my app the images are to small and I would like to try and get a larger image from the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem at all:

```
/554870764588961?fields=members{name,picture.type(large)}
```

You can use the usual size tags, or you can use width/height:

```
/554870764588961?fields=members{name,picture.width(300).height(100)}
```

More information about the tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture

Comment: Lol just found that, was just about to post that as the answer, but I'll just accept yours. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: just tested it with width/height, works too :) - thanx for the points :)

Comment: No problem, good timing lol I literally just found the answer and was about to either answer or close, but I didn't know about `.width()` `.height()` very useful info. Thanks, you rock!